# how to reject my app from iTunes Store

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect

I need to reject one of my app's from iTunes Store but I don't know how to. Does anybody know where the reject button is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your app is already on sale. They removed the reject/remove from sale in the latest version. One work-around is to go to "rights and pricing" view and to deselect all countries. It takes a few days for the change to propagate, but in a day or two the app will be shown as Developer Removed From Sale.